# Is there a way to condense my check_winner code for Tic Tac Toe?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that checks winner given the game board. My code is working as below. I'm wondering is there a shorter way to write this code?

```
board = [["X", "O", "O"],
        ["X", "O", "O"],
        ["O", "O", "X"]]

def winner(board):
    if board[0][0] == board[0][1] == board[0][2] != None:
        return board[0][0]

    if board[1][0] == board[1][1] == board[1][2] != None:
        return board[1][0]

    if board[2][0] == board[2][1] == board[2][2] != None:
        return board[2][0]

    if board[0][0] == board[1][0] == board[2][0] != None:
        return board[0][0]

    if board[0][1] == board[1][1] == board[2][1] != None:
        return board[0][1]
    
    if board[0][2] == board[1][2] == board[2][2] != None:
        return board[0][2]

    if board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2] != None:
        return board[0][0]
    
    if board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board[0][0] != None:
        return board[0][0]
    
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: This is probably more suitable for codereview.stackexchange.com. Please read their submission guidelines before posting, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there can only be one winner:

```
def winner(board):
    for row in range(3):
        if len(set(board[row])) == 1: # If there is only one value (one player)
            return board[row][0] # If all 3 squares are None, then it will return None anyway.
    for column in range(3):
        if len(set([row[column] for row in board])) == 1:
            return board[0][column]
    if board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2] or board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board[2][0] # Diagonals
        return board[1][1]
    # If no value is returned, then the function will return None by default.
```

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not understanding it. I tried:
```for row in range(3): print(set(board[row])
```
And it prints me this:
{'X', 'O'}
{'X', 'O'}
{'O', 'X'}
None
Why is this so?

Comment: Sets are a datatype that contain only one of each item. This means that if a set has length 1, the row/column contains only one symbol, implying a win.

Comment: Oh, I see. That's very clever.

Answer (score 0):

In tic tac toe, you can have either one winner or none. A good idea is to represent the board with a 3x3 array, and attribute a number to each color. I chose to use 1 for crosses and -1 for circles.

Now, to determine if either color has won, you can simply sum across a row, column and diagonal to check if the sum is equal to 3 (or -3). If the board is full and no sum of 3 (or -3) is found, then it's a tie.

```
import numpy as np

# Crosses will be 1, circles will be -1
board = np.zeros((3, 3))
board[0, 1] = 1
board[2, 1] = -1

def check_win(board):
    """
    A player has won if he completes a row, a column, or a diagonal.
    Thus, we can check the sum on each to see if a player has reached 3 or -3.

    Parameters
    ----------
    board : numpy 3x3 array representing the board.

    Returns
    -------
    winner : None, or string 'circles' or 'crosses'

    """
    # Check rows and columns
    axis0 = np.sum(board, axis=0) # Sum the columns
    axis1 = np.sum(board, axis=1) # Sum the rows
    
    # Check diagonals
    diag1 = np.sum(board.diagonal())
    diag2 = np.sum(np.fliplr(board).diagonal())
    
    # Look for crosses win:
    if np.where(axis0==3)[0].size + np.where(axis1==3)[0].size + int(diag1==3) + int(diag2==3) != 0:
        return 'crosses'
    elif np.where(axis0==-3)[0].size + np.where(axis1==-3)[0].size + int(diag1==-3) + int(diag2==-3)  != 0:
        return 'circles'
    else:
        return None
```

One more asset of representing the board with a 3x3 matrix (numpy array) is that it's more optimized, although it does not matter on such a trivial application.